# Can I move SQL Server data along one column to the left if previous column cell is NULL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have some query results that come out like this (but across 10's of 000's of rows);

```
Pol_Ref    ¦  Pol_Mix  ¦  Pol_1_Type ¦ Pol_2_Type ¦  Pol_3_Type ¦  Pol_4_Type
===========================================================================
XXXXXXSW01 ¦    Car    ¦   NULL      ¦     PC     ¦     NULL    ¦   NULL
XXXXXXSW02 ¦    Modern ¦   NULL      ¦     PC     ¦     MB      ¦   NULL
XXXXXXSW01 ¦    Car    ¦   NULL      ¦     NULL   ¦     PC      ¦   NULL 
XXXXXXSW03 ¦    Modern ¦   PC        ¦     NULL   ¦     MB      ¦   NULL
```

Column [Pol_1_Type] should always be populated with a type of Insurance policy as a minimum and then any other columns after it but in order from left to right. Thanks to end user error (don't go there) they sometimes set them up using the wrong field in the system so you end up with the values all over the place across these columns.

Is there a way I can shuffle all the values along one to the left if a NULL appears before a value? So it should look like this;

```
Pol_Ref    ¦  Pol_Mix  ¦  Pol_1_Type ¦ Pol_2_Type ¦  Pol_3_Type ¦  Pol_4_Type
===========================================================================
XXXXXXSW01 ¦    Car    ¦   PC        ¦     NULL   ¦     NULL    ¦   NULL
XXXXXXSW02 ¦    Modern ¦   PC        ¦     PC     ¦     MB      ¦   NULL
XXXXXXSW01 ¦    Car    ¦   PC        ¦     NULL   ¦     NULL    ¦   NULL 
XXXXXXSW03 ¦    Modern ¦   PC        ¦     MB     ¦     NULL    ¦   NULL
```

Comment: there is no PK on thie table?

Comment: Depends on the query, which you haven't shown us.

Comment: Also, it's unclear how you added an additional PC for row 3

Comment: I realise this is chatting, but because that data looks familiar; is that from OpenGI, per chance?

Comment: @scsimon No, it's a table I've created just to dump some results and try to make this work. It will be the main query that I apply the method of re-ordering to. Also, I've altered row three to remove the extra PC, that was my error.

Comment: @TabAlleman The query that gets this data is far, far too big to post. I've put this data into a table just to try and write some SQL that will achieve what I want to do. Eventually I will manipulate the data by using a CTE so my final statement to re-order the data I need to move uses a lot less syntax.

Comment: @Larnu Yes, well spotted! :D

Comment: Personally, then, I would look at normalising your data by use of a `VIEW`. The Tables in Infocentre are awful for normalisation; take a look at `brAgentdtls` (suitably aliased `BAD` when coding in OpenGI) and the commission columns. *shivers*

Comment: Fair enough @Phteven hopefully the solution below will suffice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't quite give the answer you were after, but I believe that's because  `SW02` has `PC` twice. I believe it should have only had it once. This gives:

```
CREATE TABLE #Policy (Pol_ref varchar(10),
                      Pol_mix varchar(10),
                      Pol_1_Type char(2),
                      Pol_2_Type char(2),
                      Pol_3_Type char(2),
                      Pol_4_Type char(2));
INSERT INTO #Policy
VALUES ('XXXXXXSW01','Car',NULL,'PC',NULL,NULL),
       ('XXXXXXSW02','Modern',NULL,'PC','MB',NULL),
       ('XXXXXXSW01','Car',NULL,NULL,'PC',NULL),
       ('XXXXXXSW03','Modern','PC',NULL,'MB',NULL);
GO

SELECT *
FROM #Policy;
GO

SELECT Pol_ref,
       Pol_mix,
       COALESCE(Pol_1_Type,Pol_2_Type,Pol_3_Type,Pol_4_Type) AS Pol_1_Type,
       CASE WHEN Pol_1_Type IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(Pol_2_Type,Pol_3_Type,Pol_4_Type)
            ELSE COALESCE(Pol_3_Type,Pol_4_Type)
       END AS Pol_2_Type,
       CASE WHEN Pol_1_Type IS NOT NULL AND Pol_2_Type IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(Pol_3_Type,Pol_4_Type)
            WHEN Pol_1_Type IS NOT NULL AND Pol_2_Type IS NULL THEN Pol_4_Type
            WHEN Pol_2_Type IS NOT NULL AND Pol_1_Type IS NULL THEN Pol_4_Type
       END AS Pol_3_Type,
       CASE WHEN Pol_1_Type IS NOT NULL AND Pol_2_Type IS NOT NULL AND Pol_3_Type IS NOT NULL THEN Pol_4_Type END AS Pol_4_Type
FROM #Policy

GO
DROP TABLE #Policy;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the comments, your expected results don't match your sample data. Specifically, you added an additional `PC` to `XXXXXXSW02`. You also haven't shown what the PK is for this table. With that in mind, this should get you started:

```
--load up the sample data you provided
declare @table table (Pol_Ref varchar(64),Pol_Mix varchar(16),Pol_1_Type char(2) null, Pol_2_Type  char(2) null, Pol_3_Type  char(2) null,  Pol_4_Type char(2) null)
insert into @table
values
('XXXXXXSW01','Car ',NULL,'PC',NULL,PC),      --I've added a PC here
('XXXXXXSW02','Modern',NULL,'PC','MB',NULL),
('XXXXXXSW01','Car',NULL,NULL,'PC',NULL), 
('XXXXXXSW03','Modern','PC',NULL,'MB',NULL)

--create a place holder primary key
;with cte as(select 
                ID = row_number() over (order by (select null))
                ,* 
                from @table)


--use aggregates with unpivot
select
    p.ID
    ,p.Pol_Ref
    ,p.Pol_Mix
    ,Pol_1_Type  =  max(case when RN = 1 then Pol end)
    ,Pol_2_Type  =  max(case when RN = 2 then Pol end)
    ,Pol_3_Type  =  max(case when RN = 3 then Pol end)
    ,Pol_4_Type  =  max(case when RN = 4 then Pol end)
from(
        select 
            ID
            ,Pol_Ref
            ,Pol_Mix
            ,Pol
            ,RN = row_number() over (partition by ID order by (select null))
        from
        (select 
            ID
            ,Pol_Ref
            ,Pol_Mix
            ,Pol_1_Type
            ,Pol_2_Type
            ,Pol_3_Type
            ,Pol_4_Type from cte) as t
        unpivot
        (
            Pol for Pols in (Pol_1_Type, Pol_2_Type, Pol_3_Type, Pol_4_Type)
        ) as up
    ) p
group by
    p.Pol_Ref
    ,p.Pol_Mix
    ,p.ID
order by
    Pol_Ref
```

**RESULTS**

```
+----+------------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| ID |  Pol_Ref   | Pol_Mix | Pol_1_Type | Pol_2_Type | Pol_3_Type | Pol_4_Type |
+----+------------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|  1 | XXXXXXSW01 | Car     | PC         | PC         | NULL       | NULL       |
|  3 | XXXXXXSW01 | Car     | PC         | NULL       | NULL       | NULL       |
|  2 | XXXXXXSW02 | Modern  | PC         | MB         | NULL       | NULL       |
|  4 | XXXXXXSW03 | Modern  | PC         | MB         | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+------------+---------+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

Feel free to add values to the sample data to test further.